# AWK - 3 for loops in END statement not desired result

Tags: linux, awk, gawk

New to AWK. I have a file with the following content:

```
FirstName,LastName,Email,ID,Number,IDToBeMatched
John,Smith,js@.com,js30,4,kt78
George,Haynes,gh@.com,gh67,3,re201
Mary,Dewar,md@.com,md009,4,js30
Kevin,Pan,kp@.com,kp41,2,md009
,,,,,ti10
,,,,,qwe909
,,,,,md009
,,,,,kor28
,,,,,gh67
```

The idea is to check whether any of the fields below the header ID matches any of the fields below IDToBeMatched and if there is a match to print the whole record but for the last field (i.e. IDToBeMatched). So my final output should look like:

```
FirstName,LastName,Email,ID,Number
John,Smith,js@.com,js30,4
George,Haynes,gh@.com,gh67,3
Mary,Dewar,md@.com,md009,4
```

My code so far

```
    awk 'BEGIN{
        FS=OFS=",";SUBSEP=",";
}

{
      # all[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5]
        a[$4]++;
        b[$6]++;
}

END{ #for(k in all){
    for(i in a){
       for(j in b){
           if(i==j){
              print i #k
                    }
                   }       
                }
    #}
}' inputfile
```

This prints the match only. If however I try to introduce another loop by uncommenting the lines in the above script in order to have the whole line for the matching field, things get messy. I understand why but I cannot find the solution. I thought to introduce a `next` statement but it's not allowed in the `END`. My AWK defaults to GAWK and I would prefer an (G)AWK solution only.

Thank you in advance.

The last field has more records because it was copied/pasted from an ID "pool" which does not necessarily has the same number of records as the files it was pasted in.

Comment: Could you show your file without added spaces and without removed commas if any? To be more clear, why the last five rows only have one field? Other thing, is there really a comma at the end of each row and does the header really exist?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I updated my question. Also, no there is not a comma at the end of the header. We can skip the header if this makes things easier (perhaps with a NR>1 ?)

Comment: In this case don't copy/paste the ID "pool", and process the two files with awk (it's easier): `awk 'NR==FNR{...;next}FNR>1{...}' idpool inputfile`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. 

Question: Does this mean that if the contents of the file were originally as described above, someone has to remove one column and paste it to another file in order to be able to get results?

Comment: @EdMorton: Sorry, it was referring to CasimirHippolyte comment. I hope question is now clearer.

Comment: If the file is big it may cause problems (use a lot of memory) since you need to store the entire content before searching records with the good IDs. With two separate files you only need to store the first one (idpool) and then the second one is processed line by line.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Oh, I see what you mean. No, this is not the case here, ID pool has 430 records so it's not going to be a problem.

Comment: Even better with two files, you can achieve your task with a simple `join` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$6];next} (FNR==1)||($4 in a){sub(/,[^,]+$/,"");print}' file file
FirstName,LastName,Email,ID,Number
John,Smith,js@.com,js30,4
George,Haynes,gh@.com,gh67,3
Mary,Dewar,md@.com,md009,4
```

Comment: Many thanks @EdMorton. It worked like a charm. Being new to AWK is it too much to ask what sub(/,[^,]+$/,"") does? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're welcome. It removes everything from the last comma on the line to the end  of the line, just like `sed -r 's/,[^,]+$//'` would. I highly recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Many thanks @edmorton for the explanation and for the suggestion (the book seems to be freely available online)

Comment: Although the book is freely available online I recommend everyone buy a copy so the author gets some small compensation for all the work he continues to put into the book, and other documentation AND providing GNU awk. I bought a copy and refer to it frequently.